# WPF custom control with generics - possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, xaml, controls

I'd like to create a custom WPF control using generics:

```
public class MyGenericTypeControl<T> : ItemsControl 
{   
   // ...
}
```

Is this possible to do? In my initial experimentation, I get design-time/compile-time XAML errors as soon as I try to add this control somewhere. This isn't surprising, as construction of my custom control requires additional information that XAML does not provide.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is limited support using [`x:TypeArguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xtypearguments-directive)

> For XAML 2006 usage, and XAML that is used for WPF applications, the following restrictions exist for `x:TypeArguments` and generic type usages from XAML in general:
>
> - Only the root element of a XAML file can support a generic XAML usage that references a generic type.
> - The root element must map to a generic type with at least one type argument. An example is `PageFunction<T>`. The page functions are the primary scenario for XAML generic usage support in WPF.
> - The root element XAML object element for the generic must also declare a partial class using x:Class. This is true even if defining a WPF build action.
> - `x:TypeArguments` cannot reference nested generic constraints.

Answer (score 3):

`XAML` doesnt support generics, you'd need to create an empty non-generic class that inherits from your generic control and use that with your `XAML`

Comment: I'd prefer that my control not know about the specific generic type being used. With this method, the non-generic deriving class would need to tell the base what the generic type is, which I'd prefer not to do.

Comment: sorry, the only solution is to create one generic control with all the important code in, then a bunch of empty classes that inherit from it using different type parameters

Comment: @kindohm Already said enough that is not possible, but i want to point out that there are not many reasons to do that. Why do you need that? You can already modify alot in WPF. `DataTemplates` allow great flexibility, with the use of `DataTemplateSelector` and Trigger that change the Template you can create almost eveything you could wish for. 
Why do you need an Control that uses a generic argument? Why not an interface? If you provide more code, we might can give you a better alternative.

Comment: @DeanChalk - _"XAML doesnt support generics"_ not entirely true.  WPF supports generics in **PageFunction**.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615540(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can only do it the other way around (a non-generic control inhering from a generic base class):

```
public class BaseControl<T> : Control
{
   // base implementation
}


public class MyControl : BaseControl<string>
{
   // ...
}
```

with the XAML for `MyConrtrol` looking as follows:

```
<local:MyControl x:Class="BaseControl"
                 x:TypeArguments="sys:String"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
                 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime">
    ....
<local:MyControl/>
```

Please note the attribute `x:TypeArguments="....."`. If your type parameter is itself generic, then you can use e.g. the following:

```
<local:MyControl x:Class="BaseControl"
                 x:TypeArguments="sys:Tuple(sys:String,sys:Int32)"
                 ...>
```

The code would be equivalent to:

```
public class MyControl : BaseControl<Tuple<string, int>>
{
   // ...
}
```